# Why I got syntax error when doing test with jest '??='

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, babel-jest

during my test i encountered an issue like this,

```
r[i] ??= [];
           
     ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
```

what should I do make it pass? I'm feeling so dumb because i can't resolve a problem like this

Comment: Which version of node you're using ?

Comment: the version of my nodejs is 14.15.5

Comment: this is supported node 15 onwards i believe.

Comment: what is the alternative to this sign? My problem is when I run the npm test the application doing great but when I want to test with jest the output shows this sign

Comment: `r[i] ??= [];` is (almost) the same as `r[i] = r[i] ?? [];` is the same as `r[i] = (r[i] === null || r[i] === undefined) ? [] : r[i]` (the "almost" is the fact that ??= will short circuit, and not do an unnecessary assignment)

Comment: Thank you nicholas this is really help me to understand the meaning of it

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade the version of your NodeJs.
Nullish Operator (`??=`) works on versions 15.14.0 or above.